# Why i am not able to read multiple strings in the server file?

Tags: c, client-server

While working in client-server programming, I have passed 3 strings in client, which will be received by server and it should be printed in there 3 times. (i.e I have used a 'for' loop which will do the read & write operations in client & server side respectively.), but in server only the 1st string is getting printed.

Please explain,

Here is my code

**server.c**

```
#include "head.h"

void readstr(int connfd ,char [][20]);
//void writestr(char * ,int);

int main(int c ,char *v[])
{
        int     sd,connfd,retbind;
        struct  sockaddr_in serveraddress ,cliaddr;
        socklen_t len;
        char buf[100] ,databuf[1024][4];
        sd =socket( AF_INET ,SOCK_STREAM ,0);
        if (sd<0)
        {

                exit(1);
        }
        memset(&serveraddress ,0 ,sizeof(serveraddress));
        serveraddress.sin_family =AF_INET;
        serveraddress.sin_port =htons(MYPORT);
        serveraddress.sin_addr.s_addr =htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        retbind =bind(sd ,(struct sockaddr*)&serveraddress ,sizeof(serveraddress
));
        if(-1 ==retbind)
        {
                perror("bind fails ");
                exit(0);
        }
        listen(sd ,4);
        for(;;)
        {
        printf("i am waiting for client\n");
        len =sizeof(cliaddr);
        connfd = accept(sd ,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr ,&len);
        if(connfd <0)
        {
        if(errno ==EINTR)
        printf("interrupt");
        continue;
        }
        printf("connection from %s\n",inet_ntop(AF_INET ,&cliaddr.sin_addr,buf ,
sizeof(buf)));
        readstr(connfd ,databuf);
        close(connfd);
        printf("\n fini one clieni");
        }
        return 0;
}

void readstr(int connfd ,char str[3] [20])
{
        int pointer=0 ,i=0, n,pos=0;
        memset(str ,'\0',sizeof(str));
        printf("\n->Connfd : %d\n",connfd);
        printf("\n----->String recieved : %s\n",str);
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        while((n=read(connfd ,str[i] ,20)) >>0)
        {
                printf("Looping while\n");
                pos =pos +n;

        }
        str[i][pos] ='\0';
        }
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
                printf("\n%s",str[i]);
        }
}
```

**client.c**

```
#include "head.h"
void send1(int ,char*);

int main(int c,char*v[])
{
        int sd,i;
        int len;
        char buf[20][4];
        struct sockaddr_in serveraddress;
        sd = socket(AF_INET ,SOCK_STREAM ,0);
        if (sd<0)
        perror("socket");
        memset(&serveraddress ,0 ,sizeof(serveraddress));
        serveraddress.sin_family =AF_INET;
        serveraddress.sin_port =htons(atoi(v[1]));
        serveraddress.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr(v[2]);

        if(connect(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&serveraddress ,sizeof(serveraddress)) <
 0)

        {
                printf("cannot connect to server");
                exit(1);
        }
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
                memset(buf ,'\0',sizeof(buf));
                printf("\n string");
                fgets(buf[i],20,stdin);
                len =strlen(buf[i]);
                if(buf[i][len] =='\n')
                  buf[i][len]='\0';

        //      scanf("%s",buf[i]);
                send1(sd ,(char *)buf);
        }
        shutdown(sd ,SHUT_WR);
}

void send1(int sd ,char *str)
{

        int n ,byteswritten =0, wr;
        char buf[1024];
        strcpy(buf ,str);
        n =strlen(buf);
        while(byteswritten < n)
        {
        printf("\nStart writing in client side\n");
        wr = write(sd , buf+byteswritten ,(n-byteswritten));
        byteswritten+=wr;
        }
        printf("\n string sent %s" ,buf);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In client.c  main:

```
    char buf[20][4];
```

change to:

```
    char buf[4][20];
```

In server.c readstr:

```
    while((n=read(connfd ,str[i] ,20)) >>0)
```

change to:

```
    while((n = read(connfd, &str[i][pos], 20)) > 0)
```

`pos` needs to be reset to 0 inside the `for` loop.

Also, the client reads 3 strings of up to 20 chars each from stdin and writes them to the socket.
The server expects 3 strings of exactly 20 chars each.

You should either use some kind of record separator, like \n, in your network protocol, or use fixed length, i.e. pad the input strings to 20 characters.

There may be more errors in your code, I stopped looking after finding these.

Answer (score 1):

It has been over 1 hour on SO and you haven't got an answer.. to what seems like a very simple problem(odd feat). you know why?

- because its very painful to go through your code.

  - document it!
  - divide it into modules - init_net(), form_pkt(), 
    send_pkt(), exit(),.. etc
- describe your problem properly.

  - how many client are you running?
  - what happens after only first strings get printed. does you code stops, loops forever what?
  - have you looked through a packet capture tool like tcpdump, wireshark, etc
- and before I get to the main problem.. I see things like "databuf[1024][4]" being passed to a function readstr() with formal arguments "char str[3] [20]".

  - couple of advice

    - run your code through a static tool analyzer to look for basic warnings.
    - strings are not a great idea to send on network, learn how to define a packet structure with header and data part, etc
    - also I believe you are looking for a Packet like communication instead of stream based. understand the difference!

I do not know the answer to that question unless you present it properly. this time and every next time.